# System.Net.Mail VB.NET 3.5 System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I have searched the net thoroughly for a solution to this and have yet to find one.
I'm trying to establish a simple mail client to send text documents as raw text through SMTP. To do this I am using the System.Net.Mail library under VB.Net version 3.5

Whenever I try to send a message, I receive a System.Net.Mail.SmtpException.
I have tried using different mail providers, under different settings and have yet to solve this problem. This problem has been tested on 3 separate computers, all with different specifications.
The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub SendEmailMessage()
Try
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
        If DataValid() Then
                'Data is valid, send the eMail.
                Dim MailReceiver As String = txtReceiver.Text
                'Create the eMail Message.
                'Dim message As New MailMessage(from:=txtMailAddress.Text, to:=MailReceiver, subject:="(MTG) <CARD> " & ID, body:="<p>" & ConstructedFileString() & "<p>")
                Dim message As New MailMessage
                Dim MessageFrom As New MailAddress(txtMailAddress.Text)
                Dim MessageTo As New MailAddress(MailReceiver)
                With message
                     .From = MessageFrom
                     .To.Add(MailReceiver)
                     .Subject = "(MTG) CARD " & ID
                     .IsBodyHtml = True
                     .Body = "<p>" & ConstructedFileString() & "<p>"
                 End With
                 'Establish eMail Client
                 Dim emailClient As New SmtpClient()
                 Dim emailCredentials As New Net.NetworkCredential

                With emailCredentials
                    .UserName = txtMailAddress.Text
                    .Password = txtPassword.Text
                    .Domain = "gmail.com"
                End With

                With emailClient
                    .Host = txtHostServer.Text
                    .Port = txtPort.Text
                    .Credentials = emailCredentials
                    .EnableSsl = chkSSL.Checked
                    .Timeout = 5000
                End With

                'Dim MailDomain As String = ""
                'Dim PositionAt As Byte = 0
                'PositionAt = txtMailAddress.Text.IndexOf("@")
                'For i = PositionAt + 1 To Len(txtMailAddress.Text)
                '    MailDomain = MailDomain & txtMailAddress.Text.Chars(i)
                'Next
                'Debug.Print(MailDomain)

                If My.Computer.Network.Ping(hostNameOrAddress:=emailClient.Host) Then
                    'Send the message.
                    emailClient.Send(message)
                Else
                    'Could not ping, do not send.
                    ErrorOut("Could not reach the eMail Server.")
                End If


           Else
                'Data is not valid, do not send the eMail.
           End If
    Else
        ErrorOut("No network could be found. Check your network configurations.")
    End If
Catch ex As Security.SecurityException
    'Security exception
    ErrorOut("A Security Exception was raised.")
Catch ex As Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException
    'Network info exception
    ErrorOut("Exception raised when retrieving network information.")
Catch ex As Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
    'Ping exception
    ErrorOut("Exception raised when pinging the network.")
Catch ex As Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException
    'Recipient exception
    ErrorOut("Mail Recipient Exception raised.")
Catch ex As Net.Mail.SmtpException
    'Mail Server Exception
    ErrorOut("Mail Server Exception raised")
Catch ex As Exception
    'Generic Exception raised.
    ErrorOut("General Exception raised", True)
End Try
End Sub
```

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Stack trace:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at NetProj.EmailDialog.SendEmailMessage() in ...
```

Comment: What are the details of the exception, including inner exceptions? That's the _real_ bit of information needed.

Comment: Pro tip - pass the exception variable `ex` to `ErrorOut` and use `ex.ToString()` to get the stack trace, inner exceptions etc.

Comment: By any chance do you have mcafee antivirus installed in those machine? I faced the same problem once but that was due to the antivirus.

Comment: @Oded
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
 at NetProj.EmailDialog.SendEmailMessage() in ...

An operation timeout is strange as the message content is 305bytes of data, and there's a timeout period of 5seconds.

Comment: @Raman Nope, I do not have mcafee installed on any machine. I have allowed the program to run through my anti-virus, anti-malware and firewall.

Comment: Can you post that in the question body? Comments are not a good place for such details.

Comment: Stack trace has been added to the bottom of the question body as requested, I have omitted the file & line number; the line in question is line 63:
    `emailClient.Send(message)`

Comment: What is the port you are using? Is it 465?

Comment: @Raman The port used for this is 465 when connecting to GMail. SSL is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the famous SSL issue with System.Net.Mail

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx

It was there in framework 3.5 not sure about 4.0 if they fixed it or not.

Comment: Guess I'll have to try out 4.0 then; thanks for the answer. I have no idea how that didn't turn up when searching, thanks again ^^

Comment: Glad I could help. I remembered this as one of my friend faced the same issue and finally he had to use some third party library. And please mark as answer and an upvote if it helps. Thanks :)

Comment: Turns out me using VS2008 puts me at quite a disadvantage, I have the .NET 4.0 Framework...but I can't reference it.
I don't think they release 2010 as freeware yet...
fun times with Microsoft :D

And I need 15 rep to upvote :( otherwise I would have already.

Comment: Wouldn't happen to know what that 3rd party lib is, by any chance?

Comment: Not sure what that library was. Sorry :(

But some i found on internet are following, you can try using these :

http://emailsender.codeplex.com/

http://dotnetopenmail.sourceforge.net/

Comment: One more 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19546/MailMergeLib-A-NET-Mail-Client-Library

Comment: Thanks, those'd be useful if I was using .NET with C# :P I'll favourite them as I know some C# programmers who may be interested in something like them.
I'll just download the trial for 2012 and see if I can fix it through that.

Comment: Ohh... I am doubtfull if that issue is fixed in 4.0 also. And I forgot you are using VB. Here is only one i found out for VB. May be this can help http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/SMTP-POP3-Email-Engine-Library-for-Visual-Basic-VB-NET.shtml